# On a construction of a conformal mapping from $\mathbb{H}$ to $\left\{x+i y: y>x^2\right\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

From Donald Marshall's complex analysis:

As an application of the Schwarz reflection principle we outline how to find a conformal map of $\mathbb{H}$ to the region $\Omega=\left\{x+i y: y>x^2\right\}$. I will include at the end of the question the statement of Schwarz reflection's principle as well as the "Corollary 8.16" which is cited under here.

First find a map $f_1$ of $\mathbb{H}$ onto the half-strip $S=\{z=x+i y: 0<x<b, y>0\}$ so that $f_1(\infty)=\infty$ (i.e., $\lim _{|z| \rightarrow \infty}\left|f_1(z)\right|=\infty$ ), where $b$ is chosen later. The function $f_2(z)=z^2$ is one-to-one on $S$ with image equal to half of the interior region of a parabola. The composed function $f_2 \circ f_1$ maps an interval $I_a=(-\infty, a]$ onto $I_{b^2}=\left(-\infty, b^2\right]$ and $[a,+\infty)$ onto the halfparabola. By Corollary 8.16 we can extend this function by reflecting the domain across the interval $I_a$ and the range across $I_{b^2}$ to obtain a conformal map of $\mathbb{C} \backslash[a, \infty)$ onto the interior of a parabola. The slit plane can be mapped onto $\mathbb{H}$ using $\sqrt{z-a}$ and the parabola can be dilated, translated and rotated using a linear map. With the proper choice of $b$ we obtain the desired region.

The construction is clear up until the point where intervals come into play, what do we mean by $f_2\circ f_1$ maps $I_a=(-\infty, a]$ onto $I_{b^2}=\left(-\infty, b^2\right]$ and $[a,+\infty)$ onto the halfparabola? $I_a$ isn't even in our domain as $\mathbb{H}$ is the open positive half plane, same for $[a,+\infty)$, even if we "somehow" included them, we have not specified what $f_1$ precisely is, so how would we know where in $S$ the image of these intervals under $f_1$ sits? Also, is $a$ taken as an arbitrary parameter?

Statements of the cited results:

Schwarz reflection principle: Suppose $\Omega$ is a region which is symmetric about $\mathbb{R}$. Set $\Omega^{+}=\Omega \cap \mathbb{H}$ and $\Omega^{-}=\Omega \cap(\mathbb{C} \backslash \overline{\mathbb{H}})$. If $v$ is harmonic on $\Omega^{+}$, continuous on $\Omega^{+} \cup(\Omega \cap \mathbb{R})$ and equal to 0 on $\Omega \cap \mathbb{R}$, then the function defined by
$$
V(z)= \begin{cases}v(z), & \text { for } z \in \Omega \backslash \Omega^{-} \\ -v(\bar{z}), & \text { for } z \in \Omega^{-}\end{cases}
$$
is harmonic on $\Omega$. If also $v(z)=\operatorname{Im} f(z)$, where $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{H} \cap \Omega$, then the function
$$
g(z)= \begin{cases}f(z), & \text { for } z \in \Omega^{+} \\ \overline{f(\bar{z})}, & \text { for } z \in \Omega^{-}\end{cases}
$$
extends to be analytic in $\Omega$.

Corollary 8.16 If the function $f$ in the Schwarz reflection principle is also one-to-one in $\Omega^{+}$ with $\operatorname{Im} f>0$ on $\Omega^{+}$, then its extension $g$ is also one-to-one on $\Omega$.